# Find all compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In $\mathbb{R}$, considering the topology consisting of the empty set and all sets containing $0$ and $1$, I need to find all compact sets.

I understand the definition of a compact set but don't know how to apply it to this situation.

I also need to find all the compact sets of a topology consisting of $\mathbb{R}$ and all sets NOT containing $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Your title says connected sets. Your body says compact.

Answer (score 5):

For the first topology :- The only compact sets are finite sets. Clearly finite sets are compact so we just need to prove that any infinite set is not compact. Let $A$ be any infinite set. Consider the open cover $\{0,1,a\}_{a\in A}$. Then since $A$ is infinite this open cover does not admit any finite subcover and hence $A$ is not compact.

Hint for the second topology :- Notice that in this topology $\{a\}\mid a\neq 0,1$ is an open set. So can you identify all the compact sets now ?

---

Edit :- (Elaborated Hint)  For the second case again let $A$ be any infinite set. Is $\{a\mid a\in A\}$ an open set ? If yes, then can you find an open cover for $A$ which does not have any finite subcover ?

Comment: I understand for the first topology, but I'm still not clear on the 2nd topology

Comment: @user215327  see my edit to the answer.

Comment: Yes,  I understand the second topology now, thanks for the extra hint

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $\{0,1,2\}$ is open.  The topology looks a lot like the discrete topology on $\Bbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$